# Proving that the median to the hypotenuse of a right triangle is equal to half of the hypotenuse

Tags: geometry

If I have a right triangle, of the form: $ABC$, with right angle at B:

[image]

Then, $BM = CM  = AM$.

Then, as I show that:

$BM = AM$

The simplest demonstration is to create another triangle equal to this one, and adjust them so that it looks like a rectangle. The diagonals of a rectangle are the same, which shows the property.

But I would like to see the demonstration, without using the property of diagonals of a rectangle, in advance thanks.

Comment: What is point M?

Comment: The midpoint of $CA$

Comment: The center of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ is ____?

Answer (score 1):

Drop the altitude from $M$ to $AB$ which will be parallel to $BC$ and find two equal right triangles.

Comment: To say that the right triangles are equal, you are assuming that the height falls at the midpoint of $AB$? to meet the criteria, SAS? ($MO,  \angle O, AB$), with $O = $ intersection between altitude and $AB$

Comment: Yes, use the [Intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) for that. And what is [SAS](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/SAS)?

Comment: How you know that the altitude from $M$ to $AB$ will be $midpoint$ of $AB$ ?

Comment: And with $SAS$ i mean to the criteria of triangle congruence, SIDE-ANGLE-SIDE

Comment: $O$ will be the midpoint of $AB$ because $M$ is the midpoint of $AC$, $MO \parallel CB$ and the intercept theorem is true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the circumcircle of ABC. Since ABC=90º, AC is the diameter.

Thus M is the circumcenter and MC=MB=MA.

Comment: So, only in a right triangle, the circumcircle is the midpoint of hypotenuse(in this case $M$) ???